# With jQuery Mobile forms, where do i put the validation message?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

According to the jQuery Mobile [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/forms-text.html), this is how you set up fields in a web form:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
   <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
</div>
```

Is there a best practice or "official" way of adding a validation message to this? I basically want the validation messages to appear under each textbox in my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any "official" way of supporting input-validation fields. What we're currently doing though, is using the combination of:

- [jquery.validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)
- jquery.unobtrusive.js (not a pre-requisite)
- asp.net mvc3 w/ Fluent validation (not a pre-requisite)

Here's an example of what the input-validation looks like for a single field:

```
<label for="Name" class="ui-input-text">Name Input:</label>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Name is required" id="Name" name="Password" type="text" class="ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-d">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

jquery.validate then takes care of inserting and displaying the correct message in the validation span. It doesn't support html5 input field-types yet, but I have a [branch on github](https://github.com/pavsaund/jquery-validation) with the necassary changes to support this.